# React functional <a> component with onClick and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I'm writing a react component in TypeScript:

```
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  href: string;
  onClick?: (e: any) => void;
}

const Input: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, href, onClick }) => (
  <a className="A" href={href} onClick={onclick(e)}>
    {children}
  </a>
);

export default Input;
```

But I get the following error:

```
The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Window'.ts(2684)
```

I'm not sure about what I'm doing wrong, any help will be welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `onClick()`, just pass reference as prop

```js
const Input: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, href, onClick }) => (
  <a className="A" href={href} onClick={onClick}>
    {children}
  </a>
);
```